# How to register generic types with multiple type arguments in dotnet core for dependency injection?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

Using Dotnet Core 3.1, I use the built in DI solution.

I'm implementing a datapump, that uses a data source and a data target, all of them generics:

```
public interface IDataSource<TData> where TData : class {}

public interface IDataTarget<TData> where TData : class {}

public interface IDataPump<TSourceData, TTargetData>
     where TSourceData : class
     where TTargetData : class {}

public class DataPump<TSourceData, TTargetData> : IDataPump<TSourceData, TTargetData>
     where TSourceData : class
     where TTargetData : class {}
```

I found examples on how to DI register the types with a single type argument, but how to register IDataPump / DataPump with two type arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Once I know the answer it's *really* simple, just had to **add a comma** to signify the number of type arguments:

```
serviceCollection
    .AddSingleton(typeof(IDataSource<>), typeof(DataSource<>))
    .AddSingleton(typeof(IDataTarget<>), typeof(DataTarget<>))
    .AddSingleton(typeof(IDataPump<,>), typeof(DataPump<,>))
```